# Xcode Build Problem (MinimumOSVersion value is invalid)

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I build app with Xcode 3.2.3 (iPhone SDK 4), following image was showed in Build Log

> Info.plist: MinimumOSVersion value is
>   invalid.  It must be a valid version: 
>   (-19024)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add a `MinimumOSVersion` to your `Info.plist` ? Because you're not supposed to, Xcode will handle that for you, based on your Base SDK and Deployment Target.

Comment: yes, I already check it. It's iPhone SDK 4.0

http://i47.tinypic.com/2n66g5g.jpg | 

http://i49.tinypic.com/105xymo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It's a problem of Target Build (not project Build). I need to check Target Build , Base SDK.

Thank All.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MinimumOSVersion in the info.plist file itself. It may have gotten set or corrupted somehow. The project info panel in your additional screenshot shows how the product file thinks the info.plist will be set and not how it actually ends up set.

Check the path to info.plist file listed in the target (not resources) to make sure you've got the right one actually being put into the built product.

Check that your SDK is set for the right platform e.g. you can't set SDK 3.2 for an iPhone only app.

Comment: <key>MinimumOSVersion</key> <string></string>

no value in MinimumOSVersion. But Code is not signed.When I add manually and submit in app store, code is not singed error appear.

I double checked, Target Version is 4.0 and Target Device Family is iPhone.

Comment: I don't think you should have a MinimumOSVersion key without a value. Not sure why it showed up empty although I don't a 4.0 template to check. Try checking the info.plist inside the app bundle itself. You certainly can't submit until you have the app built and signed.